# XCode 8: how to adapt iphone app for iPAD

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, xcode8

Even if my client made me design an iOS app only for iphone devices, now he wants me to run it in iPADS too, as a preview before loading the app in the App Store (ipads 2 or 3). My app has many constraints so that it's showed good on any kind of iphone (> 5S). So, I set the "Targeted Device Family" to "1,2" in the info.plist of the app and I tried to install it in a pair of iPADs. Even if in iphone eberything is good like the following:
[image]

the same thing does not happen in the ipad:

I do not understand why everything is so magnified and not full-screen. 
What can I do just to fix this a little?

[image]

This is what I see in info.plist --> Build Settings

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set rather this value in your Target -> General settings:

[image]

My app is working properly on the iPad even with Target Device Family set to 1.

[image]

Comment: As I wrote in my post, that what I had already tried. I set the value to "1,2" (I don't know why in XCode 8 we see 1,2 instead of Universal)...but it's not enough

Comment: I've just added a screenshot of what I see in my post

Comment: I did not create any record in Info.pList. I set everything by clicking on the file project and then on Build Settings...

Comment: Thank you...I set everything to 1 like you've showed but nothing changed for me...still the same result :(

Comment: what do you mean for "Launch screen storyboard file"? of course it is launched with the app as the usual...forgive me for my ignorance :(

Comment: I supposed I use launch storyboard...where can I check it?

Comment: Ok, I made it. As I thought I had misunderstood. I clicked on the file project --> then on target file --> Deployment Info and there I set devices to Universal.

Comment: Thank you pal! Not it's correct at last!!! Excuse me...I'm so inexperienced and ignorant!

Comment: No, your definitely not. it's a hard stuff to do settings it in Xcode, always.

Answer (score 2):

Add key **"UIRequiresFullScreen"** and set Yes to your info.plist file
[image]

Comment: Have you added new storyboard for ipad?

Comment: No, I did exactly what pedrouan's answer says

Answer (score 0):

I found these steps handy when you want your **iPhone app to adapt for iPad** -

1. Testing the complete app first
2. All screens design need to check for eg. Button or Images width and height as per iPad screen
3. Create different versions of XIBs for particular screens
4. Check if all images are in right resolutions
5. Handle auto-sizing and orientation
6. Find how and when to use the new iPad elements like split view controller, popover view controller, and popover list
7. An important tip - Be really careful never to have two popover controllers visible at the same time – it’s confusing to users and your app will get rejected if you do

Answer (score 0):

on XCode 12, you have to look for Targets -> General Tab...

[image]